# Typescript for React createContext and useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React Context file with a stateful Provider to manage cookie preferences. It all works as expected but I'm having 1 issue with Typescript. My file looks like this:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
};

interface State {
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
};

// Initialise context storage
const CookiesContext = React.createContext({});
const { Consumer: CookiesConsumer } = CookiesContext;

class CookiesProvider extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps: Props, prevState: State) {
    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.state;

    // Set cookie to store functional cookies setting
    if (functionalCookiesOn !== prevState.functionalCookiesOn) {
      Cookies.set('functionalCookiesOn', functionalCookiesOn.toString());
    }

    // Set cookie to store performance cookies setting
    if (performanceCookiesOn !== prevState.performanceCookiesOn) {
      Cookies.set('performanceCookiesOn', performanceCookiesOn.toString());
    }
  }

  toggleAllCookies = () => {
    // Store reversed state for functional and performance cookies
    this.setState((prevState: State) => ({
      functionalCookiesOn: !prevState.functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn: !prevState.performanceCookiesOn,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.state;

    const value = {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
      toggleAllCookies: this.toggleAllCookies,
    };

    return (
      <CookiesContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </CookiesContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default CookiesContext;
export { CookiesConsumer, CookiesProvider };
```

When I use this in another function component it looks like this:

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const {
    functionalCookiesOn,
    performanceCookiesOn,
    toggleAllCookies,
  } = useContext(CookiesContext);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

This throws errors such as:

```
Property 'functionalCookiesOn' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

This seems to me to do with the following line in the original file:

```
const CookiesContext = React.createContext({});
```

Because I initialise the context with an empty object (because at that stage it's got no values).

What's the correct way to initialise this or apply types to avoid this error?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide initial values. Otherwise typescript will throw the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can provide a type to your call to `createContext`

```
const CookiesContext = React.createContext<Partial<Props>>({});
```

`<Partial>` allows you to create the context without default values.

Comment: Ah right. I think this is nearly there, although I don't think the Props or State interface are correct to use since I also have the `toggleAllCookies` method passed into the Provider. Should I create a new interface for this purpose?

Comment: this page is a good guide: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/context/

Comment: Ah yeah perfect, their example creates a new interface for it. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out;-

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
};

interface State {
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
};

// Initialise context storage
const CookiesContext = React.createContext({
    functionalCookiesOn: false,
    performanceCookiesOn: false,
    toggleAllCookies: () => null
});
const { Consumer: CookiesConsumer } = CookiesContext;

class CookiesProvider extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps: Props, prevState: State) {
    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.state;

    // Set cookie to store functional cookies setting
    if (functionalCookiesOn !== prevState.functionalCookiesOn) {
      Cookies.set('functionalCookiesOn', functionalCookiesOn.toString());
    }

    // Set cookie to store performance cookies setting
    if (performanceCookiesOn !== prevState.performanceCookiesOn) {
      Cookies.set('performanceCookiesOn', performanceCookiesOn.toString());
    }
  }

  toggleAllCookies = () => {
    // Store reversed state for functional and performance cookies
    this.setState((prevState: State) => ({
      functionalCookiesOn: !prevState.functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn: !prevState.performanceCookiesOn,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.state;

    const value = {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
      toggleAllCookies: this.toggleAllCookies,
    };

    return (
      <CookiesContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </CookiesContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default CookiesContext;
export { CookiesConsumer, CookiesProvider };
```

This should do the trick and typescript will start intellisense.